# Create / make UITextField work like html select tag

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

i want to add to my application something that can work like html select tag.
i don't want to use the Picker view.
there have a solution?

Comment: show a `UITableView` modally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use these library :

TTTAttributedLabel : https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

mzselectablelabel : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mzselectablelabel

Comment: Where can i find tutorial for this?

Comment: I don't have any resources or link to explain how to use it but you can download the example from repository and learning from examples ..